# How to let the maximum number of concurrent connections be one for IE8

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, registry

Currently I can set the values of  FEATURE_MAXCONNECTIONSPERSERVER and FEATURE_MAXCONNECTIONSPER1_0SERVER in registry of Windows for IE8 to determine the maximum number of concurrent connections following the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304129%28VS.85%29.aspx)

It works when I set the values which are more than or equal to 2. But when I set the values to 1, there are still probably 2 concurrent connections. Is it possible for me to make it only one connection at the same time for IE8?

Thanks so much!

Comment: ...any reason you're trying to do this?

Comment: As I am trying to figure out the behaviors of the browser, it will be nice if the connections are built one by one.

Answer (score 0):

as per documentation [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330731(v=vs.85).aspx) the specified value of 'FEATURE_MAXCONNECTIONSPERSERVER' & 'FEATURE_MAXCONNECTIONSPER1_0SERVER' must be between 2 and 128.